# Calculating the mean of an array

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
double mean(int i, int arr[])
{
    int j, sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        sum = arr[j] + sum;
    }
    return (float)sum/i;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[100] = { NULL };
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    printf("How many numbers would you like to enter?");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);
    while (n > 100 || n < 0)
    {
        printf("Amount of numbers should be less than 0 and more than 100\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &n);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i + 1]);
    }
    printf("%f", mean(i-1, arr[i]));
    system("pause");
}
```

When I run the code it gives me a read access error. The problem is with the mean() function I created but I don't know what's wrong. Help?

Comment: For one thing, you accidentally added a `+ 1` to `scanf_s("%d", &arr[i + 1]);`  Change it to `scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);`

Comment: Have you compiled with the warnings enabled - should `mean(i-1, arr[i])` be `mean(n, arr)`

Comment: Sidenote, `"Amount of numbers should be less than 0 and more than 100\n"` seems to be the reverse of what you actually test.

Comment: Also, you're passing the wrong arguments to `mean`.  Change `mean(i-1, arr[i]))` to `mean(n, arr);`  You should have gotten a compile-time warning for this (*don't ignore warnings*).  This is where your access error is coming from, since you're passing an integer where a pointer is required.

Comment: This `while (n > 100 || n < 0)` invokes undefined behaviour as `n` is used uninitialised on the 1st iteration.

Comment: @alk - You are incorrect - the line before is `scanf_s("%d", &n);` - this could initialise the value of `n`

Comment: Hu, I missed the 1st `scanf()`, my bad. Sry. @EdHeal

Comment: However, again a nice example, where insisting on ignoring do-loops leads to more complicated, with this more mis-understandable, and with this finally more error prone code.

Answer (score 6):

> When I run the code it gives me a read access error. The problem is with the `mean()` function

Although the `mean()` function produces read access error, the actual problem is here:

```
printf("%f", mean(i-1, arr[i]));
```

You are not passing an array to your function, but its element (it is one past the end of what was written, too, so even the value that you pass is undefined).

You need to pass `i` for the length, because your `mean()` treats it as an exclusive upper limit, and you also need to pass `arr` for the array:

```
printf("%f", mean(i, arr));
```

Indexing problem when reading the data also needs to be fixed - you need to remove `+ 1`:

```
scanf_s("%d", &arr[i]);
//                 ^
```

Comment: is passing an array element to a function expecting an array legal in C or is it supported as a compiler extension?

Comment: @bkVnet For a rather archaic reason C allows conversion between `int` and a pointer (their size was the same on the system on which the first C compiler has been developed). In addition, arrays are passed to functions as pointers. These two rules combine into a requirement for compilers to allow passing an `int` to a function expecting a pointer. Most compilers warn for it, though, because it's a pretty certain error.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
double mean(int i, int arr[])
{
    int j, sum = 0;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        sum = arr[j] + sum;
    }
    return (float)sum/i;
}
int main()
{
    int arr[100] = { 0 };
    int i, n, sum = 0;
    printf("How many numbers would you like to enter?");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    getchar();
    while (n > 100 || n < 0)
    {
        printf("Amount of numbers should be more than 0 and less than 100\n");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        getchar();
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        getchar();
    }
    printf("%lf", mean(n, arr));
    getchar();
}
```

Your call to the `mean` function was wrong. You have to pass the entire array, not just one element. Change `arr[i]` to `arr`.

Other minor modifications are what I did to make it run on my system. If it works for you otherwise, then great.